# Objects are not valid as a React child react error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

could you please tell me why I am getting this error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {seo_val, text_val}). If you meant to render a collection of children,
>   use an array instead.

I am trying to hit `http` request and try to make dropdown .

```
import React from "react";

class DropDown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  render() {
    const makeDropDown = () => {
      console.log(this.data);
      return this.props.data.map(x => {
        return <option>{x}</option>;
      });
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <select>{makeDropDown()}</select>;
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DropDown;
```

**[Sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/rro780nklq)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full error message:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {seo_val, text_val}).

Error is very clear, you are trying to render an object in jsx that contains two keys:

```
seo_val: "..."
text_val: "..."
```

Write it like this, (render the value that you want):

```
return <option key={x.seo_val}>{x.text_val}</option>;
```

**[Working sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/kxq94p20x3)**

Comment: This is the correct answer, you can't just render objects, you need to render one of the values.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like `x` is an object.

Try

```
import React from "react";

class DropDown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <select>{
            this.props.data.map(x => {
              return (<option key={x}>echo</option>);
            })
          }</select>;
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DropDown;
```

And you'll see it works. Replace `echo` with `{x}` throws the error you mentioned.