# Unable to pass array of objects from parent to Child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i am trying to pass array of objects (eventually will replace with axios call for the actual data ) from parent to Child component and further from one child to other child components , i am unable pass as i get error message saying "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys ). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

/ABC.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ABCD from '../ABCD/ABCD'

const plans = [
  {
    id:'1',
    title:'option 1',
    value:'option1',
    name:'option'
  },
  {
    id:'2',
    title:'option 2',
    value:'option2',
    name:'option'
  }
]
const ABC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        plans.map( plan => {
          return(
            <ABCD data={plan} />
           );
        })
     }
    </div>

  );
}

export default ABC
```

//ABCD.JS

```
import React from 'react'

const ABCD = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data} //Here as of now data is being used , will be replaced by other child components 
    </div>
  );
}

export default ABCD
```

expected result should be the display of array of objects , but the actual output is error message saying "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, title, value, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: this is because data is an object? Do you need to render it as a string? then parse it into json first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objects are not valid as a React child react error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49033244/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-react-error)

Comment: @keysl if i want to display the entire data as string by using stringify can use it , but what if i want to use the data obtained to send to next child component , the entire data can be sent ?

Comment: @devserkan not completely , i had a look that issue before , i want to further send the props to other child components .

Comment: @nishant if you send it to a child component it will work, error is coming form the way you accessing the object

Comment: Your problem is exactly the same. You are getting the error because you are trying to render an object directly. So, if you want to send this data to other child components then do it as you do in the parent. It is not different. But, if you try to render it again like that you will get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send the data again down to any children do the same thing as you do in the parent component. Just be careful about rendering objects. You can't render objects directly, the error you got there is very clear. You need to render object's properties somehow.

```js
const plans = [
  {
    id:'1',
    title:'option 1',
    value:'option1',
    name:'option'
  },
  {
    id:'2',
    title:'option 2',
    value:'option2',
    name:'option'
  }
]
const ABC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        plans.map( plan => {
          return(
            <ABCD data={plan} />
           );
        })
     }
    </div>

  );
}

const ABCD = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SecondChild data={data} />
      <ThirdChild value={data.value} />
    </div>
  );
}

const SecondChild = ({ data }) => 
  <div>{data.id}</div>
  
const ThirdChild = ({ value }) =>
  <div>{value}</div>

ReactDOM.render(<ABC />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: have added my sandbox example , would that be correct what i implemented ?   https://codesandbox.io/embed/musing-dream-q89nr?fontsize=14

Comment: Well, if your intent is using so many child components and pass the props like that it seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is an object and  you can not rendered it as it is not a valid [`React Element`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html).

So,in this case `<div>{data}</div>`, this will not work.

Instead simply do,

```
{
   data.map((dataObject)=><div>{dataObject.name}</div>)
}
```